# Delete items in subarrays of a master array

Tags: python, numpy

let's say I have the following 3x4 array

```
master_array = [[1, 3, 4, 5], 
                [6, 5, 4, 1],
                [7, 8, 4, 1]]
```

Then, I want to delete number 4 from each of the 3 1x4 subarrays. Would I use the following?

```
for i in range(master_array.shape[0]):
    np.delete(master_array[i], 3)
```

Then, when I print the master_array, would I get?

```
               [[1, 3, 5], 
                [6, 5, 1],
                [7, 8, 1]]
```

Comment: I need to delete by means of indexes. So, I have a 14k x 136 numpy array. I want to delete 5 instances at specific indexes, let's call them indexes = [122, 125, 130, 131, 135]. Therefore, for all of the 14k subarrays, I want to delete values that are located at indexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case `master_array` is a list of lists, like in your example, you could do

```
master_array = [[1, 3, 4, 5], 
                [6, 5, 4, 1],
                [7, 8, 4, 1]]

for row in master_array:
    del row[2]
```

In case `master_array` is indeed a numpy array, you would simply do

```
master_array = np.array([[1, 3, 4, 5], 
                         [6, 5, 4, 1],
                         [7, 8, 4, 1]])

np.delete(master_array, 2, axis=1)
```

Comment: I see, I missed the axis = 1. When I print the master_array after all the deletion, I get:   <generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f2e6f4bcba0>. Edit: got it! Instead of the master_array, I entered the sub arrays. Thank you for providing the solutions to both lists and arrays.